# Is it possible to change any Euro notes in Sweden at all? Can't find anything about it

Tags: money, exchange, sweden

I've got 50 euro notes but from everything I've googled I get 0 answers on whether or not it's even possible. FOREX seems to say they don't offer any euro to SEK exchange in years. Is there any solution to this because it seems weird to just be stranded if I have my money in physical euro.

I've already got multiple cards. Trouble is literally changing the euro notes to Swedish Kronor. FOREX is very vague about what they do on their website but I've found another company called Tavex that offer it more directly. Will try both and document my experience.

For context I  live in Sweden but i've also lived in other countries so I keep both euro and SEK and some other currencies, its not just travelling. I got the money as a gift from a family member that really didn't take me seriously about Sweden not using Euro or having ways to use it.

Comment: Usually there will be some exchange service available at least on airports, if you travel by plane. But note that Sweden is pretty obsessed of not using physical cash these days, so if you have a Visa or Mastercard etc that should get you quite far.

Comment: Did you ask your bank? I used to go to Sweden a lot maybe 5-6 years ago and I don't recall having problems exchanging money

Comment: Don't ever be afraid to ask your bank - money is their job and they deal with all kinds of transactions all day every day. Worst they'll say is no. (actually the worst is they'll give you a horrible exchange rate but you'll still have to agree to it before they take the money)

Answer (score 9):

Any currency exchange in Sweden will change euros to kronor, and will accept 50 euro notes. Airports and major train stations are the most reliable places to find exchange counters, but will give you the worst exchange rate. Alternatively, your bank will almost certainly take cash deposits in euros (though you will likely have to do it at the counter, not at an ATM). Bank exchange rates for cash will range from “pretty good” to “utter robbery”, so if it’s a lot of money for you, check the rates before you go.

Answer (score 6):

Forex says they exchange EUR to SEK (with the exception of 500 EUR notes): https://www.forex.se/en/currency/sell-currency
Cost is 50 SEK. There might be better options locally depending on where you are.

Comment: Yeah. This seems to be it. You'll lose 50kr fee plus what looks like 80kr per 100eur from the unfavourable exchange rate. But unless you want to save them or somehow spent them abroad, that's the cost.

Answer (score -1):

Sneftel writes:  Alternatively, your bank will almost certainly take cash deposits in euros (though you will likely have to do it at the counter, not at an ATM).

This is wrong. The big Swedish banks only takes deposits at ATM:s with the deposit function, and only SEK.

According to the Swedish text on forex.se, they will buy Euros for 10.42, with a fee of 50SEK. Tavex.se says 10.45 with a fee of 39SEK. There is a Changegroup place on Drottninggatan 65 in Stockholm. They don't list the rates on the board, you have to ask.

For reference, the interbank rate when I am writing this is 11.07.

You could go on trip to Åland and spend your money in the dutyfree store onboard.

Comment: No link to the ferry needed, those links make this answer spammy.